# $(this).each(function() in jquery plugin returns DOM[] object instead of this object

Tags: jquery

Here's the code of my plugin..

```
$.fn.slide = function(settings) {

return $(this).each(function() {
    setInterval(function() { $.slider(opt.direction , opt.slideSpeed,this) }
}

jQuery.slider = function(direction,slideSpeed,elm) {
        console.log(elm) - > shows DOMWindow[] window as object 
    }

}


script.js   
$('#container').slide({
    slideAnimationTimeInterval : 6000,
    slideSpeed : 700,

});
```

console.log(elm) - > shows DOMWindow[] window as object  but i need #container object how can i get it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When nesting functions, you need to save `this` in another variable like this:

```
return $(this).each(function() {
    var self = this;
    setInterval(function() { $.slider(opt.direction , opt.slideSpeed, self); }
}
```

`this` is the context of the function, by default it's the global object `window`. jQuery sets it to something more useful when calling a function (e.g. an element in `.each()`). However, when your interval function is called, `this` is unbound again (=> `this === window`). By saving it in a custom variable, it's preserved in the closure of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert it into a jQuery object:

```
var $elm = $( elm );
```